# Comparing a value of a query with the values of a for loop in php

Tags: php, sql

I have a table that stores public holidays. I query that table to get all public holidays in a specific month.

```
$year = $_POST['year'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$day = date('j');
$daysinmonth = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));

$querypubhols = "SELECT phdateID, phdate, phdetail  FROM pubhols WHERE YEAR(phdate)=? AND MONTH(phdate)=? AND DAY(phdate)=?";
$stmtpubhols = $connQlife->prepare($querypubhols);
$stmtpubhols->bind_param('sss', $year, $month, $day);
$stmtpubhols->execute();
$stmtpubhols->store_result();
$stmtpubhols->bind_result($phdateID, $phdate, $phdetail);
$stmtpubhols->fetch();
$stmtpubhols->close();
```

Now i also have a for loop that displays all the days in a month based on the month selected.

```
for($day = 1; $day <= $daysinmonth; $day++){ 

    $checkday = date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0,$month,$day,$year));

    $query = "SELECT cimID, screeningdate, paymentstatus FROM cimbooking WHERE YEAR(screeningdate)=? AND MONTH(screeningdate)=? AND DAY(screeningdate)=?";
    $stmt = $connQlife->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $year, $month, $day);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($cimID, $screeningdate, $paymentstatus);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $totalnumrows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();
```

I want to be able to compare the values of the for loop with the values of the public holidays to determine if that day in the for loop is a public holiday or not. So i can state that that particular day is a public holiday.

I'm thinking something like if we take the month of June.

```
if day is 7th and 7th of June is a public holiday in the public holiday table. Then in the for loop, that day 7th of June should rea Public holiday.
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all the holidays in specific month from the database in the DB with one query and save in the result `$month_holidays`, which have all the holiday in the specific month, and it should be done. So your below foreach is unnecessary.

---

If you need below foreach, you can do it like this,

As there are many days to check if is holiday, you can use `array_column($month_holidays,null,'day')` to make `day` as the key for performance.

Then in your foreach just use `isset($month_holidays[$day_to_check])` to check if `$day_to_check` is holiday.